# How to make a window/program raise itself when called?

Tags: files, gui, window, focus

So whenever I press 'Open containing folder' in some program or when a package wants to open in the software centre, or when a torrent file wants to open in a torrent client, the icon for that program just wiggles but doesn't bring the window to view.

[image: Wiggling icon image]

This means I have to manually click on the program to raise it.

Note that this doesn't happen with everything. When I for example click on a file and select 'Open with GIMP' the program opens as normal.

I suppose I haven't isolated the issue to pinpoint exactly when it happens but I noticed it's mostly happening with software centre and 'Open containing folder'.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: 16.04 LTS version.